# How can I force module's install() function to copy files to override folder?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm creating a module which includes a new version of `list_footer.tpl` which exists in `presta\admin1234\themes\default\template\helpers\list\list_footer.tpl`

So basically all I want from my module is to copy my `list_footer.tpl` to `presta\override` folder.

Question is, how should I write the `install()` function for this purpose?

I tried:

```
  public function install()
  {
    if (parent::install() == false) {
      copy(__DIR__.'/override/list_footer.tpl', _PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/override/helpers/admin/templates/list');

      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Module's install doesn't throw any error, but `list_footer.tpl` **is not copied** to `override` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of the copy functio must be a file, not a folder. Of course the folder of the file must exist.